# Gparted can not load filesystem when PXE booting

Tags: linux, partitioning, ethernet, gparted

It looks like [gparted does not support my Ethernet card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMh6y.jpg)...  is there any way to make it so it does?  I have tried this on my netbook and through virtual box on another machine, and it keeps giving me the same error.  Neither of the lights are lit on the Ethernet card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try the latest GParted Live 0.23.0-2 in the testing branch.

[GParted Testing Directory](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-testing/)